# How can i display the data after few seconds?

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I know that i shouldn't do that but i want to make the spinner longer for the user. because for the moment the Ajax request is too quick so the user is not even able to see the spinner.

Is there anyway to put at least 5 secondes for instance, so after these 5 second the data is displayed.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url"),
  dataType: "HTML",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.spinner').show();
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('.spinner').hide();
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $('#AjaxMoreStatus').append(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: A part of me was wondering if instead of a delay if you just had the hide be a slow transition if that wouldn't look weird.  Just thinking out loud.  Like using fadeOut()

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setTimeout` to fake delays:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url"),
  dataType: "HTML",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.spinner').show();
  },
  complete: function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.spinner').hide();
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds.
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $('#AjaxMoreStatus').append(data);
  }
});
```

If you want to delay the loading too, use it on the `success` function too:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url"),
  dataType: "HTML",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.spinner').show();
  },
  complete: function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.spinner').hide();
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds.
  },
  success: function (data) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#AjaxMoreStatus').append(data);
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds.
  }
});
```